# Is the Realm method addOrUpdateObject() callable from Swift?

Tags: swift, realm

According to the docs; https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/api/Classes/RLMRealm.html the method `- (void)addOrUpdateObject:(nonnull RLMObject *)object` 
is available via Obj-C

The Swift docs; https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Realm.html <strike>doesn't mention this method.</strike> Edit: It does, I didn't notice at first.

In my Swift app, if I try and call this method `self.realm!.addOrUpdateObject(model)` then I get a compiler error `Value of type 'Realm' has no member 'addOrUpdateObject'`

Yet I see other places online, e.g. [How to properly map JSON properties to model properties in Realm.create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32380943/how-to-properly-map-json-properties-to-model-properties-in-realm-create) where people are apparently using it from Swift.

I am using Realm via cocoapods - pod 'RealmSwift' - which brings down 2 pods; Realm and RealmSwift. I can see this method defined in RLMRealm.mm I tried adding `#import <Realm/Realm.h>` to my bridging header but that didn't work.

How do I call this method from Swift?

Comment: Can you see `RLMObject`s from Swift?

Comment: I can, yes. Problem solved now though, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is available in Swift, and is [defined as](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Realm.html#/s:FC10RealmSwift5Realm3addFTCS_6Object6updateSb_T_):

```
public func add(object: Object, update: Bool = false)
```

So to get the same behaviour as the Obj-C Realm's method, you'd call it:

```
self.realm!.add(model, update: true)
```

Comment: Yes, I hadn't noticed that in the linked question I gave, they were using `RLMRealm.defaultRealm().addOrUpdateObject ` which is an RLMRealm, not a Realm...

Comment: Was just copying OP's attempted usage. Should be using optionals this way indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Realm has two methods to add objects. One is addObjects and the other is addOrUpdateObjects. 
with addObjects method, we can add objects without primaryKey.
Whereas addOrUpdateObjects must use the objects with primary key.